# url pattern with parameter is not resolving

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

i have web.xml configuration as shown below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

which maps to spring dispatcher servlet, everything works fine if i dont have any url parameter. i have email verification process where i will send a link to user who registered with us. when user clicks the link i will pass the token as

```
sample :- 
    http://hostname/tokens.html?token=1223232
```

since i have url pattern as `*.html`, i am getting "resource not available" .
since i am passing token param, spring cant resolve the path.
so is there a way so that i can add wild card after *.html* , so that spring can resolve the path ignoring param?

or any alternative way will help me.Thanks

EDIT - my handler method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/tokens")
public ModelAndView verifyToken(HttpServletRequest req, HttpSession session){
```

Comment: so if you put tokens.html without any url parameter, you don't get the 'resource not available' error?

Comment: yes, it is not working if i put url params

Comment: Show us your handler method.

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you have any other configuration that might be interfering?

Comment: So just to clarify 100% - if you go here:  http://hostname/tokens.html - you do not get any error?

Comment: no i didnt get any error. i have url mapping for *.html

Comment: The web.xml mapping ignores the query parameters - in normal configuration, all you need is the mapping you have at the start *.html.  If the exact same URL works with no params, but adding any param makes it fail then you must have some other configuration elsewhere blocking it.